# The "inverse" of the completion of a measure space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is there an "inverse" operation to the completion of a measurable space? Namely, given a measure space which contains a null set, is there a smallest $\sigma$-algebra which can be constructed by removing the measurable null subsets, such that the original measure space is the completion of the newly constructed measure space? My intuition says yes, as expressed in the following claims. However, I have not proven them. I would be grateful for comments regarding the truthfulness of the claims and where this concepts can be found in the literature. Many thanks.

Consider a measure space $(X,S,m)$, and suppose $m(A)=0$ for some $A\in S$.
Let $S_A=\{B\in S| B\subseteq A \text{ or } B^c \subseteq A \}$, where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$.

Claim 1: $S_A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Claim 2: Let $m_A$ denote the restriction of $m$ to $S_A$. Then $(X,S,m)$ is the completion of $(X,S_A,m_A)$.

Claim 3: If there exists no $C\in S$ such that $C\supset A$ and $m(C)=0$, then there is no $\sigma$-algebra smaller than $S_A$ whose completion is $(X,S,m)$.

***Corrections: above, it should say $m(A)=1$, not $m(A)=0$. Similarly, claim 3 should read: there exists no $C\in S$ such that $C\subset A$ and $m(C)=1$. Apologies.***

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why $S_A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?  Specifically, if $B \subset A$ and $C^c \subset A$ then $B, C \in S_A$ but I'm not sure why $B \cup C \in S_A$.

Comment: $C^c \subset A \implies A^c\subset C$, so $A^c \subset (B \cup C) \implies (B \cup C)^c \subset A$, where we used the result of https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Complement_inverts_Subsets. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @StackExchangeGal7 what is your interest in this question, if I may? If what you claim is true (seems so), is this operation natural/useful?

Comment: In physics, you can think of the measurable sets as observables. It can be useful to consider the smallest possible set of observables, and I think this set would correspond to $S_A$ under the above conditions.

Comment: I think you want to consider a *complete* measure space $(X,S,m)$. Otherwise, the claim 2 is clearly false.

Comment: If $m(A)=1$, then clearly there exists no $C\in S$ such that $C\supset A$ and $m(C)=0$.

Comment: @Ramiro - you're right, thank you.

Comment: If $m(A)=1$, then there exists always $C\in S$ such that $C\supset A$ and $m(C)=1$. Just take $C=A$.

Comment: @Ramiro, the correction above say $C\subset A$ (where the subset is strict). I don't think such a $C$ always exists.

Comment: One question, what about $m(X)$?  Is $m(X)=1$?

Comment: @Ramiro, of course $m(X)=1$ by virtue of $m$ being a measure.

Comment: $m$ being a measure does NOT require that $m(X) =1$.  By "measure", do you want to mean "probability measure"?

Comment: So, you want to consider a *complete probability* space $(X,S, m)$, and $m(A)=1$ for some $A \in S$. Otherwise the result is easily proved false.

Comment: You ask: "Is there a smallest σ-algebra which can be constructed by removing the measurable null subsets, such that the original measure space is the completion of the newly constructed measure space?". The answer is **no**. Counter-example: $([0,1], S, m)$ where $S$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let  $A\in S$ and $m(A)=1$. Then $(X,S,m)$ is the completion of $(X,S_A,m_A)$.  However, given any such $A$, take $p \in A$ and define $C=A\setminus\{p\}$. Then $C\subsetneq A$ and $m(C)=1$. So, $(X,S,m)$ is the completion of $(X,S_C,m_C)$ and $S_c\subsetneq S_A$.

Comment: @Ramiro, I agree with everything you wrote. But claim 3 explicitly assumes that there is no such $C$. So your example is not a counter-example to claim 3.

Comment: My counter-example is not meant to claim 3. My counter-example is meant to show that, in general, there is **not** "a smallest σ-algebra which can be constructed by removing the measurable null subsets, such that the original measure space is the completion of the newly constructed measure space".

In fact, in any complete probability space where single point sets have zero measure, there will always be such $C$ as presented in the counter-example.

Comment: Putting in other words: complete probability space  where single point sets have zero measure will **not** satisfy your claim 3.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: @Ramiro, on second thought, in your counter-example, is the extension of $m_c$ to $S$ unique even if you didn't know a priori that $m(\{p\})=1$?

Comment: The extension of $m_C$ to $S$ is unique because $(X,S, m)$ is the completion of $(X,S_C,m_C)$.  Moreover, in the extension we will recover the fact that $m(\{p\}) =0$ because  $\{p\} \subseteq X\setminus C$ and $m(X) = m(A) = m(C)= 1$, so 
$$m(\{p\}) \leq m(X\setminus C) = m(X) -m(C) = 0   $$